# XMPP : BOSH client using Blabber not getting response over proxy

Tags: xmpp

I am trying establish BOSH connection to a openfire server on port 7070 with firewall unblocked and openfire actively listening. Without proxy it works well with openfire running on same network but with proxy getting the following error,

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at rocks.xmpp.core.session.XmppSession.connect(XmppSession.java:737)
at com.geo.XMPPBosh.XMPPDemo.main(XMPPDemo.java:45)

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at rocks.xmpp.extensions.httpbind.BoshConnection$2.run(BoshConnection.java:564)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must be connected to the server before trying to login.
at rocks.xmpp.core.session.XmppSession.login(XmppSession.java:827)
at com.geo.XMPPBosh.XMPPDemo.main(XMPPDemo.java:52)
```

Below is the code,

```
BoshConnectionConfiguration boshConfiguration = BoshConnectionConfiguration
.builder().hostname("remote address").port(7070)
.proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("proxy address", 10015))).file("/http-bind/").wait(5000).build();
```

Pl help on what might be the cause or the solution.